# How do I get a value from a concatenation of a declared variable?

Tags: vba

I have a number of variables declared:

```
Dim SRC_A3 As Variant: SRC_A3 = Worksheets("SOURCES").Range("A3") ' Get filename
Dim MergeKey1 As Variant: MergeKey1 = Right(SRC_A3, 36) ' Trim the cst key out of this filename
Dim SRC_A4 As Variant: SRC_A4 = Worksheets("SOURCES").Range("A4") ' Get filename
Dim MergeKey2 ...
```

I need to obtain the Value of these variables later by creating the variable via concatenation:

```
For MKey = 2 To 6
    Dim MKeyNo As Variant: MKeyNo = "MergeKey" & (MKey - 1)
    Dim MGK As As Variant: MGK = MKeyNo
    MsgBox "MKey:" & MKey & " + " & "MKeyNo:" & MKeyNo & " + " & "MGK:" & MGK
        If IsEmpty(MGK) = False _
        Then
        Dim UnDelete1 As Range: Set UnDelete1 = Worksheets("SQL_UPDATES").Range("$B$" & MKey)
        Dim UnDelete2 As Range: Set UnDelete2 = Worksheets("SQL_UPDATES").Range("$B$" & (MKey + 1))
        Dim UnDelCode1 As String
            UnDelCode1 = "USE [nfAPCO] UPDATE co_individual SET ind_delete_flag = 0 WHERE ind_cst_key = '" & MGK & "'"
        Dim UnDelCode2 As String
            UnDelCode2 = "USE [nfAPCO] UPDATE co_customer SET cst_delete_flag = 0 WHERE cst_key = '" & MGK & "'"
        UnDelete1.Value = UnDelCode1
        UnDelete2.Value = UnDelCode2
        End If
    MKC = MKey + 1
    Cells(MKC, 1).Activate
Next
```

However, the concatenation creates a string and doesn't come back to being the declared variant (e.g., "MergeKey1") to then produce a Value (or no value). This makes the IsEmpty(MGK) always False and doesn't produce a Value in my other concatenations. The Message Box shows "MKey:2 + MKeyNo:MergeKey1 + MKG:MergeKey1", but I'd like it to produce the **Value** of "MergeKey1" and so on. If I can do it with just MKeyNo and forget MGK that's fine btw.

Any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not really possible in VBA - take a look at using an array.

Here's a simple example, it populates the array MergeKeys with the values from A1:A6.

```vb
Dim MergeKeys(1 To 6) 
Dim idx As Long

    For idx = 1 To 6
        MergeKey(idx) = Range("A" & idx).Value
    Next idx
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added more detail to the first part of my post, which is the first set of declarations (used for other parts of code), in case that helps. I'll see what I can do to make your code work with the For statement I already have setup.

Comment: The only other way I can think of approaching this would be to use a dictionary and that might not give any advantage as you would need to hard-code quite a few things.

Comment: You solution worked after adjusted it for my case. I updated my OP to show the working version. Thank you!